# Есть ли пассивная форма у слова "пытать"?

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слов

Пассивная форма по-русски называется страдательным залогом, верно?
Есть ли у глагола "пытать" страдательный залог, например "пытаться вопросом"?
(естественнее, по идее, говорить "быть мучимым вопросом".)
То же касается слова "испытываемый". Например, правильно ли "быть испытываемым кем-то/чем-то"?(или "испытуемым?)

Answer (score -1):

Понятие "пассивная форма" (глагола) в русской грамматике не используется, близкого аналога в русском языке нет. Некоторым весьма отдаленным может служить сочетание, грамматически эквивалентное пассиву в европейских языках (личная форма глагола быть + страдательное причастие), но в русском языке у 
него очень ограниченное употребление и самостоятельным залогом оно не считается.

Понятие залога используется только для причастий. И тут действиьтельно имеется некоторая аналогия: действительное причастие - актив, страдательное - пассив.

По поводу остального.

Формы "пытаться чем/кем" в русском языке нет. Ни "пытаться кем-то" ни "Быть пытаемым кем-то" не выходят за рамки окказионализмов или эрративов.

Тут можно много соображений привести в отношении того, что не всякий глагол сохраняет семантику, становясь возвратным, но в общем-то достаточно того, что глагол "пытать" имеет очень слабую переходность. Форма "пытать кого/что" существует, но причастие "пытаемый" уже имеет ограниченное употребление. А "пытанный" - уже почти за гранью нормативности.
Таким образом, форма пытаться фактически остается лишенной прямой смысловой нагрузки глагола пытать и, как это часто в таких случаях бывает, оказывается нагруженной другим смыслом.  **Пытаться** - это производить **попытку**, не "пытку" (как у глагола пытать). Таким образом, "пытаться" несмотря на признаки возвратности теряет семантическую роль обращения на себя (т.е. всяких признаков "пассивности").

Что касается глагола испытывать, то с ним таких сложностей нет. Испытываться кем-чем это действительно своего рода "пассивный" вариант конструкции "[Кто] испытывает что". Тут вам все исчерпывающе написали.

Поэтому проавильнее будет сказать, что

Comment: А вот здесь "пассивная форма" почему-то используется... http://rusgram.ru/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#333

Comment: @Aer там "**Безличные пассивная и *модально-пассивная***" *конструкции***. И уж точно там (в этом разделе) нет слова пытаться. Я примерно о том и говорил.

Comment: Это их проблемы. Не надо никуда меня приглашать. Найдете любкю грамматику, где дано определение "пассивной формы" - сам посмотрю. Остальное меня не интересует. Кстати,, мало того Кузнецов никогда не был грамматистом, он даже в своем ***толковом*** словаре умудрился столько всего насочинять...

Comment: Согласен, что *жвачка* и *жевачка* как две разные лексемы — слишком и т. д. и т. п. На Ефремову ссылаться не буду (у нее тоже страд.), потому что про нее вообще ничего не известно. Может, где-то еще фиксируется, искать специально не буду.

Comment: *Согласен, что жвачка и жевачка как две разные лексемы*  - С кем вы согласны?

Comment: С вами: "Кстати,, мало того Кузнецов никогда не был грамматистом, он даже в своем толковом словаре умудрился столько всего насочинять..." Это про то, что он насочинял (ну, или под его именем кто-то другой).